# How to use equals in set of values in hql/hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I want to use something like this below query:

```
  from myModel t
 where t.f inEqual(1,2,3,4,5)
```

instead of this:

```
  from myModel t
 where     t.f = 1
       and t.f = 2
       and t.f = 3
       and t.f = 4
       and t.f = 5
```

or maybe this:

```
  from myModel t
 where t.f inGreaterThan(1,2,3,4,5)
```

instead of this:

```
  from myModel t
 where     t.f > 1
       and t.f > 2
       and t.f > 3
       and t.f > 4
       and t.f > 5
```

actually, `inEqual` and `inGreaterThan` is not a function in hql, but i want to use something that

Comment: You should rewrite your example: `where t.f > 1 and ... and t.f > 5` could be written as `where t.f > 5` - what is, from what I guess, not the thing you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this only for multiple 'or's:

```
List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
valueList.add("1");valueList.add("2");valueList.add("3");

Query query2 = session.createQuery("from myModel t where t.f in (:values)").setParameterList("values", valueList);
query2.list();
```

For multiple 'and's and greater than etc, hibernate Criteria doesn't provide any APIs. If you want such operations, you can opt [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.4/reference/html_single/)

Query DSL provides `inAll()` and `goeAll()` etc for this purpose.

Comment: no,, it not a solution, because `in` clause operates like this clause `where t.f = 1 or t.f = 2 or t.f = 3`

Comment: @RasoolGhafari I have updated my answer. And hibernate doesn't provide any APIs for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **WHERE t.f IN ('1', '2')** as it is used in SQL.

> SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN ('1', '2');